# Why lightningStyleSheet='true' is NOT allowed in communities

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-community

Why `lightningStyleSheet='true'` is NOT allowed in communities. When we use `lightningStyleSheet` tag in VF pages, inside the ORG look and feel changes to lightning, however the same does not work in communities. When we drag n drop the VF page, look and feel still remains classic.

1. Is there a reason why salesforce is doing this.
2. Is there any other way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve (other than creating lightning component from scratch)

Thanks

Comment: it  is expected [behavior](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_lightningstylesheets.htm). **The lightningStylesheets attribute isn’t supported in Communities.**. Interesting, if we can get any SF comments about it here

Comment: For a lightning community the best approach is to use a Theme Component for the look and feel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I do not know why lightningStyleSheet='true' is not enabled in the communities or in sites but my guess is because its not in the Salesforce context and SFDC had some issues with that.

Closest thing that I achieved was to kinda "steal" slds.css.

When you go to lightning and refresh page with chrome dev tools opened in Network tab you'll see that slds.css is being fetched from the server. Additionally it is already formatted.

Just copy it save and add as a static resource.

After that I used that static resource in `<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.customCSS}" />` (Customcss was slds.css) while having `standardStylesheets="false"` and `lightningStyleSheet='true'` (despite that it should not work -> didnt check if behaviour changed without it). 
That way I recieved visualforce page used as a site automatically styled up to 75% <- page blocks were stilll not supported.

You can try the same thing in community and check if it help somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You could still use `<apex:slds/>`. You would then have to annotate all the elements you're using with CSS classes from Lightning Design System to give them a Lightning-ish look and feel.

Comment: I read <apex:slds/> does not support apex pageblock elements. I did try using apex:slds, it did change look n feel in the org but again no luck in the community still same classic feel.

Comment: Did you put a class `slds-scope` on the top-level element? Also you can use whatever VF elements you want to, but it's just a question of how successfully you can override them with CSS classes to look more Lightning-ish.

Comment: Charles, solution that user1974566 gave worked. We can download slds.css file and upload in static resource and use.

Note : you ll find slds.css only if lightningStyleSheet is set to true. In Network Tab in Chrome Dev tools you ll find the css file.