# How to use lightningStyleSheets in a salesforce community or force.com site

Tags: visualforce, community, customer-community, lightningstylesheets

I applied `lightningStyleSheets="True"` to my VF page and it does not show the lightning style when the component is added to a community. How can I achieve a lightning look in the VF page without knowing LWC?

I've tried `<apex:slds>` but to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
<apex:page showHeader="False" applyHtmlTag="true" applyBodyTag="false" controller="c2" lightningStyleSheets="True">
<head>
   <apex:slds>
    <body class="slds-scope">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Academic Year 2020-2021">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Add Scholarships">
            <apex:inputField value="{!rec.Name}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!rec.Last_Name__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!rec.Preferred_Name__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!sch.School__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!sch.Year__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!sch.Award__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!rec.Email__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!rec.Specialty__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!rec.Biography__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    </body>
   </apex:slds>
</head> 
</apex:page>
```

In a force.com site, only the headers show - nothing else:

[image]

Comment: `lightningstylesheets` attribute is not supported for communities. Check this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_lightningstylesheets.htm & also upvote this idea: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003aJGQAY. Does this workaround help? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237566/why-lightningstylesheet-true-is-not-allowed-in-communities

Comment: Thanks. I have tried `apex:slds` however it doesn't seem to be working. I've updated my code, let me know if I missed anything